# Exception following upgrade

Tags: 2013

After upgrading from Tridion 2011 SP1 to 2013 I am getting errors when loading the CME

The CME loads as below, and is not getting the required data to complete the views.

[image]

On closer inspection I see two JavaScript errors

1. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'UserSettings' of undefined from `/WebUI/Editors/CME/Views/Dashboard/Dashboard_v7.0.0.568.5_.aspx?mode=js`
2. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <  from `/WebUI/Editors/CME/Views/Dashboard/Dashboard_v7.0.0.568.5_.aspx?mode=js`

The second error reveals an error with a reference to the 2011 version of `Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.dll` show below

[image]

With the following exception

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client, Version=6.1.0.996, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddfc895746e5ee6b' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) at System.Signature.GetSignature(Void* pCorSig, Int32 cCorSig, RuntimeFieldHandleInternal fieldHandle, IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle, RuntimeType declaringType) at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.get_Signature() at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.GetParameters() at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceReflector.ValidateParameterMetadata(MethodInfo methodInfo) at System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.CreateOperationDescriptions(ContractDescription contractDescription, ContractReflectionInfo reflectionInfo, Type contractToGetMethodsFrom, ContractDescription declaringContract, MessageDirection direction) at System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.CreateContractDescription(ServiceContractAttribute contractAttr, Type contractType, Type serviceType, ContractReflectionInfo& reflectionInfo, Object serviceImplementation) at System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.LoadContractDescriptionHelper(Type contractType, Type serviceType, Object serviceImplementation) at System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescription.GetContract(Type contractType) at System.ServiceModel.Description.WCFServiceClientProxyGenerator.GetClientProxyScript(Type contractType, String path, Boolean debugMode, ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) at System.Web.Script.Services.ProxyGenerator.GetClientProxyScript(Type type, String path, Boolean debug, ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint) at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.CachedJsService.get_Contents() at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.CachedJsService.WriteContents(HttpResponse response, List`1 writtenResources) at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.CachedJsGroup.WriteContents(HttpResponse response, List`1 writtenResources) at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.CachedJsGroup.WriteContents(HttpResponse response, List`1 writtenResources) at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.CachedJsModels.WriteContents(HttpResponse response, List`1 writtenResources) at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Common.HttpUtilities.OutputWithHTTPCacheHeaders(ICachedResource resource, Nullable`1 cacheDuration) at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Http.HTTPCoreResourceProvider.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

I can not find any reference to 2011 dll's, any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the system, and can you confirm the `Tridion Content Manager Service Host` service is started before you try to access the CME?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the error complaining about a missing reference to the 2011 Core Service Client DLL, I'm wondering if you perhaps have any UI extensions (Editors or Models) installed which require this (and instead need to just use the available Core Service DLL with the 2011 endpoint, which is still there).

First thing I would recommend is always a reboot and after that reboot ensure that all services are correctly started. Some services can have a delayed start, so make sure you check if everything started correctly by keeping an eye on the event log.

If the reboot does not help and you still get the error, edit your `..\Tridion\web\WebUI\WebRoot\Configuration\System.config` file and disable (comment out) all custom Editors and Models you find in there. If after that you change the `modification` attribute, you can try refreshing the CME and see if that solved the problem. Then you know it was an extension and can try enabling them one by one to find out which one it was that needs your attention.

Comment: Thanks Bart! It was an custom addon in the System.config. Now to eliminate them one by one to find which one.

Answer (score 0):

You can troubleshoot using steps given in the [documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2013&lang=en-US#addHistory=true&filename=TS_UIs.xml&docid=concept_BE18935A53FA40E296AB3738E6F74325&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_BE18935A53FA40E296AB3738E6F74325) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion))

Comment: That is definitely a useful guide, but I think Chris was already able to determine the exception. :-)

Comment: right, but it could be useful for someone coming to this post.